# Is it possible to have more than one pretty-faces.xml file?

Tags: prettyfaces

I've inherited a project from another person in the company I'm working now, it uses jsf, and it uses pretty-faces to hide the urls.

Issue here, is that pretty-faces.xml file is kind of large(it's up to 492 lines), and I wonder if there is a way to divide it in several files and keep it working the same, just for the sake of organization and maintenance.

I've read the [pretty-faces docs](http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html_single/#getstarted.prettyconfigxml) but I'found nothing on this direction.

Any answer is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can add a context parameter to tell PrettyFaces about your configuration files:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>com.ocpsoft.pretty.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/custom-mappings.xml,/META-INF/another-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

See:

http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/GettingStarted.html#getstarted.prettyconfigxml

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I tried to to it separating one small portion of it and adding the lines to my web.xml file, but when I am testing, I get a "NullPointerException" when trying to navigate. I don't know where to look into.  I'm using pretty-faces along with jsf 2.1 and primefaces 3.5

Comment: Please post all details including the full stacktrace to our forums: http://ocpsoft.org/support/forum/prettyfaces-users/